# Wordpress Page of Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, custom-pages

I am building a personal website to host my university work, personal projects and photos etc.

The menu is a hierarchical structure made up of `pages` and `links`. Take my university pages for example. What I would like to achieve is to display posts that are related to the module code which is the `page's` `slug`.

I've used the following link http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#A_Page_of_Posts and managed to get it working but I have hard coded the module code into the template, meaning for each module I will have to have a separate template and the only thing that will be different from one file to the next is 5 characters which isn't great for code re-use.

What I am asking, is, is there a way to *get* the `slug` from the page I'm looking at and use that for the `WP_Query` arguments.

If you go to http://michaelnorris.co.uk/ and look at the menu structure. Navigate to University -> Year Three -> Individual Project, you will notice the url is http://michaelnorris.co.uk/uni/three/ci301 where `ci301` is the module code for the `Individual Project`. I want to have this *system* on each of the module pages so that I can tag `posts` and they are displayed in the relevant module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I actually found the answer myself, but for others looking to do the same. Below is a solution.

Solution found here on the Wordpress.org Codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#A_Page_of_Posts

Name the file `pageofposts.php` and edit the Page within the Wordpress Dashboard and set the Template (in the dropdown) to 'Page of Posts'. Bingo!

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page Of Posts
*/

/* This example is for a child theme of Twenty Thirteen: 
*  You'll need to adapt it the HTML structure of your own theme.
*/

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php 
        /* The loop: the_post retrieves the content
         * of the new Page you created to list the posts,
         * e.g., an intro describing the posts shown listed on this Page..
         */
        global $post;
        $slug = get_post( $post )->post_name;

        if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

              // Display content of page
              get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
              wp_reset_postdata();

            endwhile;
        endif;

        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            // Change these category SLUGS to suit your use. category_name is comma separated.
            'tag' => $slug, 
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $list_of_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <?php if ( $list_of_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( $list_of_posts->have_posts() ) : $list_of_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <?php // Display content of posts ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```